# Add or remove items from array in sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I'd like to add or remove items in a sessionStorage array according tow what gets selected or not in several HTML selects. The single functions will then call a main showOrHide function which will add visibility classes or not according to the presence of ids in the array.

I want to add an ID to the array only if either the filter = '' (i.e. all) is selected, or if the ID is already missing from the array.

I'm getting herratic behaviour though, like the array getting emptied on the second selection. What am I missing?

HTML:

```
<select class="form-select form-control" onChange="filterPersonsEducation()" id="education">
<option value="" selected="selected">Any education</option>
<option value="GT">GT</option>
<option value="CC">CC</option>
<option value="ET">ET</option>
</select>
<div id="accordionPe">
<div class="accordion-item">
<h2 class="accordion-header" data-id="id1" data-education="GT">Alik</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function filterPersonsEducation() {

    var arrayIDs, arrayEducation, input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    
    input = document.getElementById('education');
    filter = input.value;
    ul = document.getElementById("accordionPe");
    li = ul.getElementsByClassName('accordion-item');
    arrayIDs = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('arrayIDs'));
   
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByClassName("accordion-header")[0].dataset['education']
        id = li[i].getElementsByClassName("accordion-header")[0].dataset['id']
        var arrayEducation = a.split(', ');
            if ((filter === "" || arrayEducation.includes(filter)) && (!arrayIDs.includes(id))) {
                        arrayIDs.push(id);
                        sessionStorage.setItem('arrayIDs', JSON.stringify(arrayIDs));
                        console.log('added ' + id)
                }
            else {
                arrayIDs.splice(arrayIDs.indexOf(id), 1)
                sessionStorage.setItem('arrayIDs', JSON.stringify(arrayIDs));
        console.log('removed ' + id)

            }
            
    }
}
```

[This](https://codepen.io/lguariento/pen/QWZQVQZ) is a CodePen to show what I want to do. I want to concatenate the two `selects`, so to speak, and show only the items with that id.

Comment: What is `accordionPe`? It's not in the html

Comment: `filterPersonsEducation()` not defined

Comment: It was on the same line of ``` and not showing up. Thanks.

Comment: now this line gives errors `li = ul.getElementsByClassName('accordion-item');` becuz `ul` is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You should check for that and initialize it to an empty array if it's null.

```js
arrayIDs = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('arrayIDs'));
if (arrayIDs == null) {
  arrayIDs = [];
}
if ((filter === "" || arrayEducation.includes(filter)) && (!arrayIDs.includes(id.toString()))) {
  // add ID to arrayIDs
} else {
  // remove ID from arrayIDs
}
if ((filter === "" || arrayEducation.includes(filter)) && (!arrayIDs.includes(id.toString()))) {
  arrayIDs.push(id.toString());
  sessionStorage.setItem('arrayIDs', JSON.stringify(arrayIDs));
  console.log('added ' + id)
} else if (arrayIDs.includes(id.toString())) {
  arrayIDs.splice(arrayIDs.indexOf(id.toString()), 1);
  sessionStorage.setItem('arrayIDs', JSON.stringify(arrayIDs));
  console.log('removed ' + id)
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't solve my issue. I was initialising the array already (I omitted the code here) and he rest of your code looks the same as mine (although with the .toString() method added).